# Comparison of two strings in PHP, and array_slice

Tags: php, csv, string-comparison, slice

I feel like I've done something very silly, but I can't work out what it is.
I'm running through an array of arrays generated by `fgetcsv()`. What I want is to split the array in two at the spot where the value in one line differs from the one in the next.
This code results in `$first` holding all but one of the arrays, and `$second` holding the last - completely ignoring the string comparison. `strcmp()` results in the same thing.

```
$csv = array();
$file = fopen('A.csv', 'r');
while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    $csv[] = $result;
}
fclose($file);

array_shift($csv); //gets rid of the CSV headers
$rows = count($csv);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $rows; $i++){
    if ($csv[$i][1] != $csv[$i+1][1]){
        $first = array_slice($csv, 0, $i);
        $second = array_slice($csv, $i);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the CSV file:

```
NAME,MATCHNAME,CHROMOSOME,START LOCATION,END LOCATION,CENTIMORGANS,MATCHING SNPS
A,person_one,2,20945970,23287731,2.48,500
A,person_one,2,233444593,234432885,1.56,500
A,person_one,4,99184637,100861136,1.24,500
A,person_two,1,154990798,157871980,2.8,700 //Here's where the new array should start
A,person_two,1,67136078,70785393,2.28,800
```

**EDIT:** My expected `$first` for this example would be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => person_one
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 20945970
        [4] => 23287731
        [5] => 2.48
        [6] => 500
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => person_one
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 233444593
        [4] => 234432885
        [5] => 1.56
        [6] => 500
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => person_one
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 99184637
        [4] => 100861136
        [5] => 1.24
        [6] => 500
    )
)
```

And my expected `$second` would be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => person_two
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 154990798
        [4] => 157871980
        [5] => 2.8
        [6] => 700
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => person_two
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 67136078
        [4] => 70785393
        [5] => 2.28
        [6] => 800
    )
)
```

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't quite understand your question. What is your expected `$first` and `$second`?

Comment: I've edited my question with the expected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing what you want, but when it gets to the last iteration, it compares whatever's in the last line with `null`, so it overwrites `$first` and `$second`.

Try adding `break;` after the assignments to break out of the loop when the condition is met.